# Bootstrap Validation - Java Eclipse

Tags: java, webservice, jsp

Cuando ingreso informacion en una caja de texto se valida pero tambien se valida otra caja de texto automaticamente, como solucionaria para que no se valida esa caja de texto automatica. Aca dejo una imagen y el codigo.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Mantenimiento del Paciente</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Imagenes/logo.ico">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrapValidator.css">
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>

</head>
<body><br>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="id_form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend style="text-align:center"><label>MANTENIMIENTO DEL PACIENTE</label></legend>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><label>Datos del Paciente</label></legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-1">Código:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly name="codigo">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Nombre:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre"/>
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Apellidos:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">DNI:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni"/>
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaNacimiento"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_form').bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            nombre: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'El nombre es un campo obligatorio'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/,
                        message: 'The first name can only consist of alphabetical and space'
                    }
                }
            },
            apellidos: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'El apellido es un campo obligatorio'
                    }
                }
            },
            dni: {
                row: '.col-xs-2',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'DNI es un campo obligatorio'
                    },
                    integer: {
                        message: 'DNI solo admite números'
                    },

                    stringLength :{
                        message:'El DNI solo admite 8 números',
                        min : 8,
                        max : 8,
                    }
                }
            },            
        }   
    });

//     // Validate the form manually
//     $('#validateBtn').click(function() {
//         $('#id_form').bootstrapValidator('validate');
//     });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a poner cada control (y su label) dentro de un form-group diferente:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Nombre:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Apellidos:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos"/>
    </div>
</div>
```